# Calculating and Interprit Area from Imported ShapeFile in SQL Server Geospatial

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

This question is about how to properly calculate the Area of a surface in SQL Server.

Setup:

I found GeoJson from [Gmaps example](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geojson_polygon.html):

I then converted part of the GeoJSON to a shape file with mygeodata.cloud.

This is to get the data into a database:

```
CREATE TABLE [Demo1] ([ID1] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, [FID] bigint, [geom] GEOMETRY);        
ALTER TABLE [Demo1] ADD CONSTRAINT [enforce_srid_geometry_demo1] CHECK (geom.STSrid = 4326);     

declare @p3 sys.geometry
set @p3=convert(sys.geometry,0xE6100000010409000000000000749A405AC047FAF6F4B4DE4340000000749A405AC037BB28019BDE43400000004470405AC0372177549FDE43400100000C3F405AC037BB28019BDE4340000000981C405AC0175481D798DE4340000000CC06405AC037BB28019BDE4340000000CC06405AC00C447EB6B1DE4340000000A857405AC08E1B24E0B3DE4340000000749A405AC047FAF6F4B4DE434001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003)
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [Demo1] ([geom],"FID") VALUES (@GeometryColumn,@FID);',N'@GeometryColumn Geometry,@FID bigint',@GeometryColumn=@p3,@FID=0
```

I then want to get the area:

```
 DECLARE @a geometry = (SELECT TOP 1   [geom]   FROM [TestSQLSpatial].[dbo].[Demo1])

SELECT @a.STArea()  AS Area;
```

The area calculates as `6.48979403194971E-06`
The unit of measure is meters.

```
 SELECT unit_of_measure FROM sys.spatial_reference_systems WHERE spatial_reference_id = 4326
```

[Screenshot of whole example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8boTn.png)

This was just an example.

I'm trying to get the Area for real (larger) areas, how do I get the real surface area in Square KM's or Square Meters? What does the value `6.48979403194971E-06` mean? A real life scenario I have to calculate, follows the same process (and shows correct on Google Maps), but the answer is : `0.862311233936197` when I know for a fact this is hundreds of hectares.

Comment: Haven't looked in depth but the first thing I notice is that you're using `geometry` when you should be using `geography`. Your area result of 6 * 10^-6 makes sense if interpreted as **square** meters , if SQL has interpreted your input as meter coordinates rather than lat long